# Foreground Service getting Crashed and restart when User killed the app (Nougat)

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

I am facing a trouble here where i want a foreground service should run untill its task get completed and once task get completed foreground service should stop. But the problem here is even if its Foreground Service the Service is getting killed when user close the  app only in Nougat Version. I have checked Marshamallow,Oreo, Android pie version the scenario is working fine. But In Nougat and MI phone this scenario is not working correctly.

Below is Service code which i am running as a demo

```
public class MyForeGroundService  extends Service {
    private static final String TAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE = "FOREGROUND_SERVICE";

    public static final String ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE = "ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE";

    public static final String ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE = "ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE";


    public static final String PRIMARY_CHANNEL = "default";

    public MyForeGroundService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE, "My foreground service onCreate().");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(intent != null)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            switch (action)
            {
                case ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE:
                    startForegroundService();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foreground service is started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE:
                    stopForegroundService();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foreground service is stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    /* Used to build and start foreground service. */
    private void startForegroundService()
    {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = notificationBuilder();
        // Start foreground service.
        startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());


        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("SERVICE_CONNECTED");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

            }
        },10000);
    }

    private void stopForegroundService()
    {
        Log.d(TAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE, "Stop foreground service.");

        // Stop foreground service and remove the notification.
        stopForeground(true);

        // Stop the foreground service.
        stopSelf();
    }



    public NotificationCompat.Builder  notificationBuilder(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL)
                .setContentTitle("Dummy Title")
                .setContentText("Dummy Message")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText("Big text Message"
                        ))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_white);
            mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_white);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getResources().getString(R.string.feroz_channel_name);
            String description = getResources().getString(R.string.feroz_channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, name, importance);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager1 = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager1.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }


        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, MyForeGroundService.class);
        stopIntent.setAction(ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent stopPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, stopIntent, 0);
        mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new,"STOP",stopPlayIntent);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateForegroundServiceActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
         mBuilder.setUsesChronometer(true);

        return mBuilder;
    }
}
```

Below is code which start the service from activity

```
startServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateForegroundServiceActivity.this, MyForeGroundService.class);
                intent.setAction(MyForeGroundService.ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    startForegroundService(intent);
                } else {
                    startService(intent);
                }          
            }
        });

        Button stopServiceButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_foreground_service_button);
        stopServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateForegroundServiceActivity.this, MyForeGroundService.class);
                intent.setAction(MyForeGroundService.ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    startForegroundService(intent);
                } else {
                    startService(intent);
                } 
            }
        });
```

I think startForeGroundService works well but startService is not working as expected. The behaviour is so confusing, When i kill the app foreground service gets restarted , but if i open the app and press a button to stop the service i can see intent sent to the Service. But still the service is running.

[image: This is lenovo Phone on which Service get restarted]

PS: I want a service which run for like 10 Mins irrespective of App is in Background or not. It shouldn't get Restarted at any cost. For e.g if i am playing a music from background its should play till end. it should stop as soon as music ended. I dont want it to be restart
Below is logs when i start the service on button click and killed the app :

```
2019-02-15 13:35:56.091 11120-11120/sample.androido.com.myapplication D/MyForeGroundService: My foreground service onCreate().
2019-02-15 13:36:01.956 1459-3975/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service sample.androido.com.myapplication/.services.MyForeGroundService in 1000ms
2019-02-15 13:36:02.975 1459-1509/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 11170:sample.androido.com.myapplication/u0a154 for service sample.androido.com.myapplication/.services.MyForeGroundService
2019-02-15 13:36:03.674 11170-11170/? D/MyForeGroundService: My foreground service onCreate().
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) for `startForegroundService()` method.

> Note that calling this method does not put the service in the started state itself, even though the name sounds like it. You must always call ContextWrapper.startService(Intent) first to tell the system it should keep the service running, and then use this method to tell it to keep it running harder.

According to the above statement, you should call `startService()` first and then `startForegroundService()`

Comment: So u mean to say I should call both method first start service then start Foreground?

Comment: if possible vivek can you please provide a snippet of code please

Comment: Read the link I have added, you will understand what you have to code

Comment: ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(CreateForegroundServiceActivity.this);
                    cw.startService(intent); i did this but not helping

Comment: vivek can u check the logs  updated in question also like Service getting crashed and restarted

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui why are you throwing exception in your onBind() method ? That may be the cause of your service crashing

Comment: i have no binded service what should i do ? i made it return null but still the service is gettting crashed

Comment: remove the onBindMethod(). You are not creating a bound service, so that is not required

Comment: but extending of service class  need  implementation of onBindMethod

Comment: You can simply return null from onBind() method in that case

Comment: yeah i did but still service getting crashed on app and restarted

Comment: i cannot post here its big so posted on my github gist. Please have look https://gist.github.com/Feroz-Istar/b9f6efd22623d45336503afc24dfb934#file-service_crash_logs. I can see some exception in Phone System UI at com.android.systemui.statusbar.NotificationData.remove(NotificationData.java:296) there is null pointer exception

Comment: So what are you doing in that notification data class ?

Comment: its not me its device logs which are throwing exception. When app is killed the notification gets disappear and then again its reappear. The exception is coming from com.android.systemui from lenovo device. I dont understand in why this is happening in this device specially while with rest of devices of mine is working fine

Comment: One more thing I saw is that you might require to enable multidex in your app, I can see some class not found exceptions too

Comment: i enable multi dex also but foreground service is getting restarted